# Hitting F1 in Visual Studio 2010 does not launch a help MSDN page

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have got Visual Studio 2010 installed on my computer.
Hitting F1 while the cursor is on a .Net element - a class name for instance - does not launch the corresponding MSDN page in my web browser.
Hitting F1 works for some of my workmates at my company.

What option do I need to configure to get it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Visual Studio, choose `Help`-`Manage help settings`.  At that point, you can setup the MSDN Library to use the online reference.

Once this is done, F1 should trigger the proper MSDN page.